# Step down 9-36V to 5V: Best and cheap way to power a Raspberry Pi

Tags: transformer, circuit-design, step-down

I've seen a lot of solutions across the web: MP2307, OKI-78SR-5, LM2596 and so on.  I have to power a Raspberry Pi 4 that draws around 1.8/2A in a smart and effective way (low ripple, extended range from 9V to 36V.)

Also, I need to design and integrate this step down circuitry to a custom PCB that has very low area available (2x3cm.)

Does anyone have experience with those step down converters? What do you recommend?

Comment: Best usually doesn't mean cheap. Lots of folk have experience but you are not really defining the problem in terms of ripple voltage or if it needs to be isolating, what surges may be present on the incoming supply or what current load profile your load is. Product recommendations are off-topic BTW.

Comment: With Murata it shouldn't go wrong, they are specialists in that field, but the OKI....won't supply 2A.

Comment: 2x3cm is plenty of area for a buck converter of that caliber. You can easily use parametric search in the websites of the many suppliers to find suitable IC/Modules. I usually go to Texas Instruments and Linear Tech (now Analog Devices).

Answer (score 2):

Given you want to accommodate a 4 fold range of input voltage and a minimum input voltage of 9v on a small footprint  linear regulation is a non starter due to high power dissipation.

You should take a look at buck converters since they can accommodate the voltage ranges you mention and convert to 5v with high efficiency and less waste heat. The standard rpi4 psu is rated at 3A.

Answer (score 2):

I do think that OKI isn't enough to power your Rpi4. Cheap converters could become very expensive at the end.

Beside Murata there are also other reputable brands like Traco Power, Recom, ....

https://recom-power.com/en/search/products/search/parametric-search/search-parametric?3

https://www.tracopower.com/int/series/tsr-3

Answer (score 2):

If you can deal with 0.32mm extra width, the Bellnix BTI24-05S300D should fit the bill.  It's 20.32mm x 25.4mm and gives you 5V at up to 3A from a 9-36V input with max 70mV ripple.  It's a little short on documentation and I haven't heard of Bellnix before, but maybe someone else here has.